# Move even lines to last of odd lines except last line

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have some txt files in `E:\Desktop\prog\OCR` directory that each file have a format like following:

```
Fytytyotyrtyttyran
57.338
CtyOtyBtyOtyL
13.318
AytLtGtyOtyL
10.254
Ayttssemtybtyly
5.33
BtyAtySItyC
2.061
AytryPL
1.53
Lirtysyrtyp
1.466
Ctry
0
Patretsyttrcal
0
1965 Q2
```

Now i want to convert above list to following format:

```
Fytytyotyrtyttyran;57.338
CtyOtyBtyOtyL;13.318
AytLtGtyOtyL;10.254
Ayttssemtybtyly;5.33
BtyAtySItyC;2.061
AytryPL;1.53
Lirtysyrtyp;1.466
Ctry;0
Patretsyttrcal;0
1965 Q2
```

note that last line of each file no need any change.
**I wrote following python script for this:**

```
import os

input_directory = r'E:\Desktop\prog\OCR'
output_directory = r'E:\Desktop\prog\OCR\output'

def merge_even_odd_lines(input_path, output_path):
    with open(input_path, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as infile:
        lines = infile.readlines()

    merged_lines = []
    for i in range(0, len(lines), 2):
        if i + 1 < len(lines):
            odd_line = lines[i].strip()
            even_line = lines[i + 1].strip()
            merged_lines.append(f"{odd_line};{even_line}")
        else:
            merged_lines.append(lines[i].strip())

    with open(output_path, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as outfile:
        outfile.write('\n'.join(merged_lines))

def process_files(directory_path):
    if not os.path.exists(output_directory):
        os.makedirs(output_directory)

    for root, _, files in os.walk(directory_path):
        for file in files:
            if file.endswith('.txt'):
                input_file_path = os.path.join(root, file)
                output_file_path = os.path.join(output_directory, file)
                merge_even_odd_lines(input_file_path, output_file_path)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    process_files(input_directory)
    print("Conversion completed successfully.")
```

**But my script convert my files to following format:**

```
Fytytyotyrtyttyran;57.338;CtyOtyBtyOtyL;13.318
AytLtGtyOtyL;10.254;Ayttssemtybtyly;5.33
BtyAtySItyC;2.061;AytryPL;1.53
Lirtysyrtyp;1.466;Ctry;0
Patretsyttrcal;0;1965 Q2
```

**where is my script problem?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're processing the output files as input files, because the output directory is a subdirectory of the input directory, and `os.path.walk()` goes into subdirectories. So each file gets merged twice.

If you don't need to process the directory hierarchy recursively, don't use `os.path.walk()`, just loop over the files in `input_directory`:

```
for file in glob.glob(os.path.join(input_directory, "*.txt")):
```

If you do need to recurse, the simplest solution is to move the output directory out of the input directory. Another choice is to check whether `root` is in the `output` directory and skip those files.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `zip()` and slicing for the task:

```py
with open('your_file.txt', 'r') as f_in:
    lines = [line for line in map(str.strip, f_in) if line]

for a, b in zip(lines[:-1:2], lines[1:-1:2]):
    print(f'{a};{b}')

print(lines[-1])
```

Prints:

```
Fytytyotyrtyttyran;57.338
CtyOtyBtyOtyL;13.318
AytLtGtyOtyL;10.254
Ayttssemtybtyly;5.33
BtyAtySItyC;2.061
AytryPL;1.53
Lirtysyrtyp;1.466
Ctry;0
Patretsyttrcal;0
1965 Q2
```

Comment: I edited my script to [https://hastebin.com/share/edepokonid.python](https://hastebin.com/share/edepokonid.python) but still i get incorrect result!

Comment: The problem isn't in the `merge_even_odd_lines()` function. If you run it by itself it works fine.

Comment: @PubgMobile Try to filter empty lines, now you have `lines = infile.readlines()`, do instead `lines = [line for line in map(str.strip, infile) if line]`